# Jquery click doesn't work with custom cursor (div following mouse)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div following the mouse, to make a custom cursor, but the issue is, then no jquery click listeners on anything works, because technically I'm clicking the "cursor", not what I'm trying to click on, I've tried changing the z-index but that doesn't seem to help,

Any help appreciated.

Comment: please share relevant code that you have tried so far

Comment: Add `pointer-events: none;` to the cursor div, or position it a few px to the side of the cursor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A div following the mouse is unusual, but if you have to do that use

```
pointer-events: none;
```

This will make it so that your div does not catch any pointer events and thus allows you to click through it. I suggest trying to use cursor with a custom image though, if that is an option for you. For reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor

```
/* URL and coordinates, with a keyword fallback */
cursor: url(cursor1.png) 4 12, auto;
```

Simply apply that to whever you want to see the custom cursor (for example your `body`)